# Rewrite rules conflict .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Case 1 and Case 2 are not working together. If I remove Case 2 from .htaccess file, case 1 will work. If I write case 2 before case 1, case 2 will not work, while case 1 will work.

Case 1:

```
RewriteRule /(.*)\.html storycategory.php?story=$1
```

Example:

```
http://localhost/romoko1/story/bedroom.html
```

Case 2:

```
RewriteRule /(.*)\.html tag.php?tag=$1
```

Example:

```
http://localhost/romoko1/tag/home-interior.html
```

Comment: Try `story/(.*).html  storycategory.php?story=$1` and `tag/(.*).html tag.php?tag=$1` !

Comment: Its not working dear...

Comment: Okey ! Please check out my new answer !

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in your `.htaccess` :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule story/(.*).html storycategory.php?story=$1
RewriteRule tag/(.*).html tag.php?tag=$1

</IfModule>
```

Don't forget to enable `rewrite_module`.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: #No  its not sub-directory
RewriteBase /romoko1/

Comment: i want this url as output  www.romoko.com/story/bedroom.html

Comment: This is second url and i want output as http://www.romoko.com/tag/home-interior.html

Comment: I've tested the updated answer manually, please check it out !! if it's not working then you have a different problem !